# Datediff between 2 rows based on specific values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like the below..

```
DateCreated         Changed_By_User_ID  Change_Info     ResourceID  (No column name)
2022-08-24 20:01:44.937     1876          Entry           400377    NULL
2022-08-24 20:02:40.013     1876          Exits           400377    1
2022-09-23 14:19:52.140     1876          Entry           400377    42857
2022-09-23 14:20:16.807     1876          Exits           400377    1
2022-09-23 14:34:48.617     1876          Entry           400377    14
2022-09-23 14:35:24.210     1876          Exits           400377    1
```

What I want to achieve is how long each User_ID was viewing each record based on the DateCreated and the Change_Info columns. I have added a column using the below code..

```
datediff(minute,lag(l.DateCreated,1) over (partition by ResourceID, changed_by_user_id order by l.[DateCreated] asc),l.[DateCreated])
```

However as you can see in the table, this is calculating the difference between the exit and then the next entry.. I only ever want it to calculate the diffence between Entry -- > Exit. All values against an Entry row should show as 0.

Can anyone advise the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Could you show your expected output? Also what happens if an entry ot exit is missing? Much easier to evaluate expected results (including any corner cases) than a wordy description.

Comment: Add a `CASE` to check the value of `Change_Info`?

Comment: yeah the case one would work... didn't think of that at all. Thank you